# Solution for $ y(x) - ae^{y(x)} = f(x) $ involving Lambert W function

Tags: exponential-function, roots, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

I need to solve an equation of the type:

$$y(x) -ae^{y(x)} = f(x)$$

with $a>0$. Furthermore, the expression for $f(x)$ can't be evaluated analytically (it's the solution of a differential equation that I find applying finite differences).

I read about the Lambert W function and I was wondering if one could apply it to find a general solution of this type of equation. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Generalizations) it's given a solution for a similar case involving real constants, but I am not sure if the same result could be applied in the case where one has a function $f(x)$.

Comment: Fix $x=a$, a constant. Then $y(a)$ and $f(a)$ are also constants. Now use the solution you found. Now change $a$ to a different value. Does the solution have the same form? If it does, it is valid for general $x$, provided that the ranges of $y(x)$ and $f(x)$ satisfy the necessary conditions to stay on a single branch of Lambert function. Otherwise we would need to consider different solutions for different domains

Comment: *Hint.* Write $z=-ae^y$ and notice that $ze^z=-ae^{f(x)}$.

Comment: @YuriyS so, If the argument of the W function is between $-1/e$ and $0$ then I have to consider the two branches and have some way of distinguishing between the two solutions, right? (like how sometimes when solving a second order algebraic equation the negative solution doesn't make sense, for example).

Comment: Yes, pretty much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Yuriy S made nice comments to which I should not add anything.

The solution is "simply"
$$y(x)= f(x)-W\left(-a\, e^{f(x)}\right)$$ The problem is now the fact that Lambert function is multivalued and, depending on $a$ and on the value of $f(x)$ for a given $x$, you could be obliged to change from one branch to another one.